# Filter an array to keep only one result

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got an array that can contains up to 3 roles:

```
const roles = [
  "SUPERVISOR",
  "USER",
  "ADMIN"
];
```

I want to filter this array to only keep one role: Supervisor, User or Admin.

I was thinking about about a filter function like this:

```
const result = roles.filter(role => {
  if (role === "ADMIN");
  else if (role === "SUPERVISOR");
  else if (role === "USER");
  return role
});
```

But it returns every role...

Comment: "only keep one role" Which role, exactly?

Comment: You do nothing in your `if/else` blocks, and then just return the role.

Comment: This is how we store our roles in our DB, it's not optimal I know. The goal is to have only a string : role = Admin (if there is admin in the array). And only Supervisor is there no admin but a Supervisor, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an array of the sorted roles and find the top role by checking the roles array.

```js
const
    roles = ["SUPERVISOR", "USER", "ADMIN"],
    result = ["ADMIN", "SUPERVISOR", "USER"].find(role => roles.includes(role));

console.log(result); // "ADMIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter method works by iterating through the items in a loop, like a for each loop. Every time the inside of the loop returns `true` the data is kept in the new array (`result`). In your case you return `role` which is a string and is *trueish*, and hence the string will remain in your filtered list.

If you had a list of elements, you could do something like this:

```
function filterBasedOnRole(role, arr) {
     return arr.filter(r => r == role)    
} 
let arr = ["SUPERVISOR", "USER", "ADMIN", "ADMIN", "USER", "ADMIN", "ADMIN"];
filterBasedOnRole("ADMIN", arr)
--> out: (4) ["ADMIN", "ADMIN", "ADMIN", "ADMIN"]
```

Note that the function is a shorthand and might as well be written as:

```
function filterBasedOnRole(role, arr) {
     return arr.filter(r => {
        return r == role   
     })  
}
```

If you were to iterate through a list of object, that had a name and a role for instance, your code would look like this instead:

```
let arr = [
   {
      "name":"Boss Man",
      "role":"SUPERVISOR"
   },
   {
      "name":"Regular Joe",
      "role":"USER"
   },
   {
      "name":"The King of Kings",
      "role":"ADMIN"
   }
]
function filterBasedOnRole(role, arr) {
     return arr.filter(user => {
        return user.role == role   
     })  
}
filterBasedOnRole("ADMIN", arr)
--> out: [{name:"The King of Kings", role: "ADMIN"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution using a function:

```js
function role(roles) {
  var role = roles.includes("ADMIN")?"ADMIN":
  roles.includes("SUPERVISOR")?"SUPERVISOR":
  roles.includes("USER")?"USER":
  "";
  console.log("Out of ["+roles+"], *"+role+"* wins... :)");
  return role;
}

console.log(role(["SUPERVISOR", "USER", "ADMIN"]));
console.log(role(["USER", "SUPERVISOR"]));
console.log(role(["USER"]));
console.log(role([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for a "maximum" role solution, where the order is defined as "ADMIN" > "SUPERVISOR" > "USER" then you can use `Array.reduce`

```js
const maxRole = (currentRole, nextRole) => {
  if (nextRole == 'ADMIN') { return nextRole }
  if (nextRole == 'SUPERVISOR' && currentRole != 'ADMIN') { return nextRole }
  return currentRole
}

const roles = [
  "SUPERVISOR",
  "USER",
  "ADMIN"
];
console.log(`My best role is: ${roles.reduce(maxRole)}`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments and post, I think this might be what you are looking for:

```js
const roles = [
  "SUPERVISOR",
  "USER",
  "ADMIN"
];
var role = var role = roles[Math.round(Math.random())*roles.length];
```

Comment: there is no random in the question ..